# Element is not clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on an item that corresponds to my dictionary value "name" and "color," but I keep getting a traceback error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (520, 815)
```

In short, I'm trying to create an auto-checkout script that takes in parameters from the dictionaries below (i.e. ITEM_INFO, SHIPPING_INFO and BILLING_INFO) and sends them to the Selenium driver. The problem is that after the browser cannot find the product name after navigating to the product category because the product name is not clickable. I tried to mitigate this by using an explicit wait, but I still get the same error message.Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass in values to ITEM_INFO and then have selenium pass in the values.

Comment: What's the traceback error?

Comment: @StevenByrne I just updated it in the question description. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. I created a driver instance, created `item_info` based from the dictionary you described, passed them to your function and `colorway.click()` worked just fine. Please provide additional details.

Comment: @Reti43 Coud you post your code? I'm curious to see if you caught something I didn't.

Comment: Show us YOUR code. Please read [how to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Reti43 I just updated the code in the description. Lmk what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you try to click on an element which is not clickable. In this case WebDriver throws an exception:

> WebDriverException: ... Element is not clickable at point (520, 815)

You have to find out why the page does not allow the element to be clicked. It can either be due to (a) some business logic or (b) a timing issue. For (a) change your test case so that the element becomes clickable. For (b) use an [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the element to become clickable

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but turns out it was a bug in chromedriver. Everything worked once I switched to geckodriver.