# how to store an auto generated value in robot framework and use it at a later stage?

Tags: robotframework

There is an auto generated number that appears on a textbox, I want to store it so that I will use it in a second  test file.
This is how my code looks like:

```
*** Keywords ***

Search for Product Code  #keywords to search for a stored value
    [Arguments]  ${prodCode}  
    Selenium2Library.Input Text xpath=//[@id="abcdefg"]  ${prodCode}  #pointing to the searchbox
    ${storedPCode}=  Selenium2Library.Get Text  xpath=//*[@id="mnopqrst"]  #pointing to the textbox with an autogenerated number
    [return]  ${storedPCode}
```

I get this error when I execute the script:

```
webDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="submit" value=" refresh" class="btn btn-green"> is not clickable at point (404, 308). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal"></div>
```

Please help, Thank you

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Würgspaß  'webDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="submit" value="
refresh" class="btn btn-green"> is not clickable at point (404, 308). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal"></div>'

Comment: The problem is not related to your question at all. And it is not related to robot-framework. You have to find out why the page does not allow the element to be clicked. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386365/element-is-not-clickable/47390197#47390197

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Element is not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386365/element-is-not-clickable)

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: @FihlangTsoananyana You may need to store it in txt file

Comment: @Würgspaß The textbox that has the value I want to store is disabled on the application, there is no way it can be clickable, I want to use that value, in another textbox in order to do other processes.

Comment: @FihlangTsoananyana I suggest you to delete this question and create a new one (or rewrite this question completely). Your real question is not about robotframework as such but: _How to retrieve a value from a disabled web element using RF's Selenium2Library_. One possibility would be to use keyword _Execute Javascript_ with a suitable JS expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get Value instead of Get Text

`${storedPCode}=  Selenium2Library.Get Value  xpath=//*[@id="mnopqrst"]`